# Is there a correct techincal term used to describe a phrase or name consisting of a pair or group of homonyms; i.e., "Spring Spring?"

Tags: terminology

Is there a term to describe names or phrases consisting of two or more homonyms, such as "Spring Spring" or "Rock Rock?"

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Sainadh, I'm afraid oronym is not what I am looking for. Oronym describes a pair of phrases which are homophonic, such as "ice cream" and "I scream." 

I am looking for a term to describe a single phrase like "shot shot." I am specifically looking for a term which describes a phrase where the words are not merely redundant, but homonyms possessed of different meanings, in which one acts as an adjective or adverb and the other as a noun or verb. For example, Neapolitan ice cream from Naples, Italy, might be called "Neapolitan Neapolitan."

Comment: This is normally called repetition.

Comment: I wonder if there are any humans (in English language countries) with the name "John John" (So, "John" can be an unusual lastname, as well as a common firstname.)

Answer (score 1):

After much research it would appear that the best answer is: "Antanaclasis!"  There are apparently some rather infamous examples such as: "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo."

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antanaclasis Except that 1. it may have more than two repetitions 2. not necessarily adjacent.